# How is the Comparable interface is marker interface, with its compareTo() method?

Tags: java, oop, terminology, comparable, marker-interfaces

How is the `Comparable` interface is marker interface, even though it defines a `compareTo()` method?
Please explain detail.

Comment: Where did you hear or read this? I've never heard Comparable called a marker interface before.

Comment: Who said it was a marker interface? `Serializable` is, has no methods.

Comment: i dont think its a marker interface, as it has methods declared (well, a method...)

Comment: Nowhere in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) for the class says it's a marker interface :/

Answer (score 6):

A *marker interface* is just a design pattern. So even if you read around "X is a marker interface" this doesn't really mean anything apart from "X is an interface with no methods declared".

Since `Comparable<T>` has one method then it is not used as a marker interface.

A marker interface is useful when you want to attach data to a type to be able to use this data in specific situations, this is not the case of `Comparable`, which is used to provide an effective interface.

I don't even think that the definition of marker interface is used in javadoc to describe empty intefaces such as `Serializable` (not sure about it though).

Answer (score 1):

It is not a marker interface. Marker interface in Java for  e.g. Serializable, Clonnable and Remote  are used to indicate something to compiler or JVM; indicate a flag to compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [Wikipedia on *Marker interface pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern) (emphasis mine):

> [...] class implements a marker interface, and methods that interact with instances of that class test for the existence of the interface. Whereas a **typical interface specifies functionality** (in the form of method declarations) that an implementing class must support, a **marker interface need not do so**. The **mere presence of such an interface indicates specific behavior** on the part of the implementing class. Hybrid interfaces, which both act as markers and specify required methods, are possible but may prove confusing if improperly used.

That being said `Comparable<T>` *can* be called a marker interface, but it's confusing and I've never heard this before.

I can't imagine a class testing whether some object implements `Comparable<T>` without actually down-casting and calling `compareTo()`.